# How to get "getValue" value from a var of type Datepicker

Tags: jquery

I'd like to get the date value from a variable of type jquery Datepicker for instance:

```
var dp = $("#datepicker")datepicker();
```

How should I get my "getDate" value from my dp variable?

Comment: Which datepicker? jQuery UI?  Bootstrap?

Comment: If jQuery UI, reference the methods available on the API: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: If you're using one of the bootstrap datepicker plugins, you should also reference their API methods: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `datepicker()` returns the reference of the jQuery element so you can use [`getDate` method](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate) to get the date.

```
dp.datepicker('getDate')
```